# The chat timeout counter is hard to read

Tags: bug, design, chat

[image]

Perhaps a lighter shade could be used?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic here and better asked at Meta.SO

Comment: @Adnan No. First, the styling of chat depends on the site, so a question about the styling of the Sec.SE chat is about Sec.SE and not SE in general. This question would in fact be off-topic on MSO since it is about a specific site which isn't SO. Second, questions that apply SE-wide are on-topic on child meta sites. [Don't make Rebecca Chernoff cry.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on/89232#89232)

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the info. Good to know. VTC retracted.